# Use Postgres RECURSIVE to create a view of descendants

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, recursive-query

I am trying to create a postgres view, containing a kind of hash map of an hierarchical structure.

My hierarchy table looks something like:

```
------------------
| id | parent_id |
------------------
|  1 |      null |
|  2 |         1 |
|  3 |         1 |
|  4 |         2 |
```

For performance reasons i need, in my program code, a hashed represantation

`1 => [2,3,4]; 2 => [4]; ...`

I can get all children of 1 by this query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
    h_tree(id, label)
  AS (
    SELECT
      id,
      label
    FROM hierarchy
    WHERE parent_id = 10000
    UNION ALL
    (
      SELECT
        h.id,
        h.label
      FROM h_tree v, hierarchy h
      WHERE h.parent_id = v.id
    )
  )
SELECT array_to_json(ARRAY_AGG(id)) AS children_ids
FROM h_tree
```

This query gives me a (json encoded) list of all children of "10000".

My question:

How do I wrap this in a form where the output of this query is

```
---------------------------------
| hierarchy_id | children_ids[] |
---------------------------------
|            1 |        [2,3,4] |
```

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**

I made an error in my question. I need all descendants, thanks @pozsfor pointing that out.

Furthermore my example was flawed, I edited it.

Comment: Perhaps use `Select label as hierarchy_ID, string_agg(id,',') From h_tree group by label` instead of array_to_jason to combine multiple rows into one for each hierarchy_ID/label?  I'm a bit confused becuase I don't see where hierarchy_ID is coming from unless it's label.

Comment: You *would* need a `RECURSIVE` query for all **descendants**. For just children, all you need is a simple `JOIN` (or rather, a simple `SELECT` if you don't need anything other than the children's `id`). F.ex. http://rextester.com/VGTKE62744

Comment: Thanks, but i didn't make myself clear in the question, i need all descendants, not only the children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE children AS
   (SELECT parent_id AS id, id AS child_id
    FROM hierarchy
    WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL
    UNION
    SELECT children.id, h.id
    FROM children
      JOIN hierarchy h
         ON h.parent_id = children.child_id
   )
SELECT hierarchy.id,
       string_agg(children.child_id::text, ',')
FROM hierarchy
   LEFT JOIN children USING (id)
GROUP BY hierarchy.id;

┌────┬────────────┐
│ id │ string_agg │
├────┼────────────┤
│  1 │ 2,3,4      │
│  2 │ 4          │
│  3 │            │
│  4 │            │
└────┴────────────┘
(4 rows)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I hat an error in my question. Hopefully you can have another look :)

Comment: I rewrote the answer for the changed question.

Comment: Many Thanks! Works perfectly! (And fast as hell)